# How to migrate from Azure Table storage to SQL Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

We use Azure Table storage in our project and we want to migrate to SQL Azure. Is there any simpler way to migrate ?

Comment: "Simpler" way? Compared to what? There's not necessarily a simple answer to this especially because you're shifting from a key/value store to a relational store, with very different schema characteristics.

Answer (score 4):

The simple way to move data from Azure Table Storage to SQL Azure is using Azure Data Factory. You can refer to the tutorials [Build your first Azure data factory using Azure Portal/Data Factory Editor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-build-your-first-pipeline-using-editor/) & 
[Move data to and from Azure Table using Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-table-connector/) to know how to do it.